# Javascript prerender page shows broken link?

Tags: javascript, html, prerender

Here is the code I'm using

```
var hint = document.createElement("link");
hint.setAttribute("rel", "prerender");
hint.setAttribute("href", link);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(hint);
```

Here is output

```
<link rel="prerender" href="https://mylink.com/?a=321&amp;c=72616&amp;s1=Source49&amp;s2=56_51952910468619620">
```

What could have caused it?
The link with `&amp;` instead of `&` in link will not work right?

Comment: Try to `console.log(link)`

Comment: [rel=prerender === Deprecated && This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/prerender)

Comment: How have you confirmed that this specific operation is causing the problem?  What is the runtime value of `link`?  Please update the question to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.